# Customizing bibliography's style and appearance

Tags: bibliographies

How do I to make this bibliography looks better?

[image]

Here the code that I've used :

```
\chapter*{Nethographie}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nethographie}

{[}N9{]} https://kuler.adobe.com (Consulté en Janvier 2014)

{[}N10{]} http://http://jsfiddle.net/ (Consulté en Janvier 2014)

{[}N11{]} https://kuler.adobe.com/explore/newest/ (Consulté en Février 2014)

{[}N12{]} http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465\%{}28VS.85\%{}29.aspx (Consulté en Février 2014)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a complete, minimal document showing the relevant settings for your bibliography. Also, please add the possible `.bib` file used.

Comment: You're going to have to give more information than that. How would you like the bibliography to look better? What are you unsatisfied with? Is there some citation style you're trying to conform to? How did you generate the image in your question? Could you provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE)?

Comment: @Dennis, Hum.. The text is not aligned correctly and is not nice to look. And, there is a weird space between `http`and `://` that I can't remove.

Comment: For reference N10, there are two consecutive http://. Is that a typo? Btw, in french, months names are to be written in lowercase.

Comment: @Bernard, it's a typo. Are you sure ? look at the title here : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9vrier_2013

Comment: @user3289501 I'd guess that the title is in uppercase simply because it is the title. Look at all of the other instances of février in the body of the site.

Comment: @user3289501: yes, I'm quite sure – except of course at places where any word has an initial capital. Cf *Lexique des règles de l'Imprimerie nationale*. Same rule for days names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make the bibliography section manually, you can use [`thebibliography`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thebibliography) environment; the `\url` command (from the `url` package) can be used to typeset URLs using mono-spaced font:

Since the `french` module for `babel` is loaded, you can change the name for the bibliographical section using

```
\addto\captionsfrench{
  \renewcommand\bibname{Nethographie}
}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\addto\captionsfrench{
  \renewcommand\bibname{Nethographie}
}

\begin{document}

As we see in~\cite{kuleraa}

\begin{thebibliography}{9999}
\bibitem[N9]{kuleraa} \url{https://kuler.adobe.com} (Consulté en Janvier 2014)

\bibitem[N10]{jsfiddle} \url{http://http://jsfiddle.net/} (Consulté en Janvier 2014)

\bibitem[N11]{kulerb} \url{https://kuler.adobe.com/explore/newest/} (Consulté en Février 2014)

\bibitem[N12]{microsoft} \url{http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465\%{}28VS.85\%{}29.aspx} (Consulté en Février 2014)
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this way, besides having an automatic formatting for the entries, you have the ability to reference the items in your document using the \cite command, as I did in my example code.

The main elements are:

1. The `thebibliography` environment: you use this environment to declare your bibliographical entries; the environment has a mandatory argument wich will be used to give the proper spacing around the labels. In my example I used `9999` which means there's provision for labels having the width of four characters.
2. Inside this environment, you declare each entry using `\bibitem` which has a mandatory argument for the key that is used in eventual citations in the document. This command also has an optional argument that can be used to change the default numeric label. For example,

   ```
   \bibitem[N9]{kuleraa}
   ```

   instruct to define a new entry; this new entry will be labelled `N9` and will have assigned a key `kuleraa` that can be used in the document to make a citation using `\cite{kuleraa}`.

Notice, however, that doing your bibliographies by hand means that you are responsible for the sorting of the entries and for their formatting.
Tools such as [`BibTeX`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtex) or the package [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) can do those tasks for you.

Comment: Thanks for response, how do I to change `References` to `Nethographie`, please ?

Comment: @user3289501 That depends. Are you using the `babel` package? If so, with which language?

Comment: yes, I'm using `babel`, language : french.

Comment: @user3289501 Which language do you declare as an option for `babel`?

Comment: language : french.

Comment: @user3289501 please see my updated answer.

Comment: If you add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble you can get `é` and any other accented characters to show up in the output image.

Comment: @Mico Sure, I know; I was tired last night :-) In some hours I'll add them.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to make your bibliography by hans, here is a way, using the `enumitem` and `url`packages:

```
        \documentclass{book}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
        \usepackage{lmodern} 
        \usepackage{url} 
        \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 

        \begin{document}

        \chapter*{Nethographie}

        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nethographie}

        \begin{enumerate}[label ={[N\arabic*]},start = 9]
        \item \url{https://kuler.adobe.com} (Consulté en janvier 2014)
        \item \url{http://http://jsfiddle.net/} (Consulté en janvier 2014)
        \item \url{https://kuler.adobe.com/explore/newest/} (Consulté en février 2014)
        \item \url{http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465\%{}28VS.85\%{}29.aspx} (Consulté en février 2014)
        \end{enumerate}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I've used your solution at final and upvoted it.